# PDO Sql query not working

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am using the following code to insert in MYSQL table:

```
try{
    $sql="INSERT INTO tblmtd(t_id,t_name,mem_id) VALUES(':t_id',':t_name',':mem_id')";
$stmt=db::con()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':t_id',$tid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':t_name',$tNm,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':mem_id',$mId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
}catch(PDOException $ex){
   die("Error occured:".$ex->getMessage());
}

$tid variable has value=1;
$tNm variable has value='CBSE';
$mId variable has value=9
```

when this piece of code is run then no error is generated but in MYSQL table i observe the field values as 't_id'=0, 't_name'=t_name, 'mem_id'=0.I just don't understand what is wrong with my code.However, one funny thing is that when i try to acomplish the same task using the below mentioned code, proper data is inserted into the table.The code is

```
$db= new Database();
$db->open();
$sql="INSERT INTO tblmtd(t_id,t_name,mem_id) VALUES('$tid','$tNm','$mId')";
$db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using PDO to bind parameters, keep in mind that it appropriately quotes and escapes for you automatically. This means you need to remove the quotes from your `VALUES` statement, as follows:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tblmtd(t_id,t_name,mem_id) VALUES(:t_id,:t_name,:mem_id)";
```